# UIScrollView implementing a delegate

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a view controller that has three scroll views as subviews. I would like to have the child scrolling views inform the parent view controller whenever the page has changed.

I thought I would do this by setting up a delegation pattern. My child (a subclass of UIScrollView) sets it up in the header file:

```
@interface TriptychScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    id delegate;
}

- (id)delegate;
- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate;
@end

@protocol RCScrollDidChange
@optional
- (void)scrollView:(TriptychScrollView *)scrollView imageDidChange:(NSNumber *)index;
@end
```

The source file has the delegate accessor methods:

```
- (id)delegate {
    return delegate;
}
- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate {
    delegate = newDelegate;
}
```

Unfortunately, this means my setting the delegate to self call is being ignored:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

.. and therefore the two methods `scrollViewDidScroll:` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` are not getting called! This means I've effectively lost control of my scrolling views.

Am I doing this incorrectly? Or is there a better way for the child subviews to send messages back to their parents?

Comment: Do the three scroll views all have their own controller instances?  Why are you setting "self" to be the delegate?  Usually you would have the parent create the child and set itself as the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not understand the whole problem, but I dont see a reason for implementing your own subclasses of UIScrollView, and if you are insistent on doing so, dont shadow it's .delegate property or make sure and call super.

I would approach this by doing the following:

assuming all of these scrollviews are contained by some other view;

```
UIScrollView *a = ....
a.delegate = self;
a.tag = 1;

UIScrollView *b = ....
b.delegate = self;
b.tag = 2;

UIScrollView *c = ....
c.delegate = self;
c.tag = 3

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (scrollView.tag == 1) 
     //handle a
   else if (scrollView.tag == 2)
     //handle b
   else if (scrollView.tag == 3)
     //handle c
}
```

Comment: **1) Why did I subclass UIScrollView?** It's a relatively complicated class, with only three UIViews declared to show many images in an infinite circle. It could all be done in the view controller, but this way I saved having to say
`if (scrollView.tag == 1) else if (scrollView == 2) else ..`
many times over.

Comment: **2)** And yes, the (now) obvious answer is that the parent view controller should be the delegate, not the child scroll views. That made everything work easily. Thanks, and to JAgostoni